# How to build Yocto hddimg on i.MX7 to boot from usb stick

Tags: usb, yocto, boot, dongle, imx7

I have an i.mx7 som. I want to build a Yocto image which I can dd onto a usb stick to boot from. I believe that I want an hddimg image but cannot see how to create one (I have sdimg which works prefectly).

I would appreciate advice.

I have set IMAGE_FSTYPES to "hddimg" but get "ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'syslinux'"

The SOM is the Technexion i.MX7. Layers are:

```
layer                 path                  priority
=======================================================
meta                  sources/poky/meta          5
meta-poky             sources/poky/meta-poky     5
meta-oe               sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe  6
meta-multimedia       sources/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia  6
meta-freescale        sources/meta-freescale     5
meta-freescale-3rdparty  sources/meta-freescale-3rdparty  4
meta-freescale-distro  sources/meta-freescale-distro  4
meta-powervault       sources/meta-powervault    6
meta-python           sources/meta-openembedded/meta-python  7
meta-networking       sources/meta-openembedded/meta-networking  5
meta-virtualization   sources/meta-virtualization  8
meta-filesystems      sources/meta-openembedded/meta-filesystems  6
meta-cpan             sources/meta-cpan          10
meta-mender-core      sources/meta-mender/meta-mender-core  6
meta-mender-freescale  sources/meta-mender/meta-mender-freescale  10
```

Comment: which meta-layers do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you certainly do not want an hddimg, as this is a mostly deprecated format for x86 systems. On ARM, you almost never want syslinux :-)

Usually your SOM comes with a Board Support Package in the form of a layer, which includes the MACHINE definition which in turn defines the IMAGE_FSTYPE that this machine likes for booting. If in doubt, consult the manual or ask your vendor.

Having said that, if you specify SOM and layers in use we can have a look if publicly accessible, but without those details it is impossible to give a proper answer.